# Does Swagger (Asp.Net Core) have a controller description?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm building a REST service that will host multiple controllers (microservices). As a whole, lets call the service "Bob". So swagger displays "Bob" / "A collection of Bob Microservices". Then the controller names are listed. Right now, it just shows XYZ, ABC, etc. Is there a way to maybe have swagger show "XYZ - A collection of XYZ APIs" or something of that sort?

Seems like swagger shows the ///Summary on the methods, but not on the controllers.

Comment: Quick note: multiple controllers are certainly not microservices

Comment: @KierenJohnstone -- in this sense, that's how they wanted to do it. Obviously not pure REST... but we'll have multiple POST methods in the controller specified with routes. So you'll be able to post to /Bob/XYZ/method1, /Bob/XYZ/method2, etc. That's why they are calling it microservices.

Comment: That's just a Web API, perhaps not using REST.  Microservices are something entirely different: a collection of separately versioned, built and (usually automatically) deployed services, each typically with its own data store(s) and bounded context.  You're just talking about "Controllers"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to maybe have swagger show "XYZ - A collection of XYZ APIs"

Yes. Here is one of the easiest ways. The ASP.NET Core version of Swagger leverages the [`ApiExplorerSettings`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute.cs) attribute. You can set the `GroupName`.

```
public class BobController 
{
    [ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName="XYZ - A collection of XYZ APIs")]
    public IActionResult MyAction() 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The group name appears in the Swagger UI with the group's actions listed as operations underneath.

[image]

**Edit:** Here is an idea based on SledgeHammer's comment.

Swagger ASP.NET Core uses an `IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider` to build its description groups. We could implement our own, using the default  `ApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider` for inspiration, and register our provider during `Startup.ConfigureServices`. Our implementation would make the [`ApiDescriptionGroups()`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer/ApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider.cs#L36-L48) method return the `GroupName` associated with each action's controller. Then we could put the `ApiExplorerSettings` attribute on each controller instead of onto each action.

Comment: Thanks Shaun, it seems like I need to put this on every method in the controller? I tried putting it on the class (since the attribute says its allowed), but Swagger didn't pick that up.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Yes. We do need to put that attribute onto each method in the controller. Time permitting, I will research a way to apply it at the controller level.

Comment: is this will work in .Net4.8 web API or only in .Core

Answer (score 23):

If you are using Swashbuckle 4.0.x and ASP.NET Core 2.x, you may have something like this which also works by including the NuGet package for **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations**.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations;

namespace MyExample.Controllers
{
/// <summary>
/// Example of a .NET Core controller based on the controller name
/// api/[controller] on ValuesController becomes api/values
/// endpoint: "/Values" from [controller] and name of controller , which is "ValuesController"
/// </summary>
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[SwaggerTag("This is an example controller generated by ASP.NET Core 2.x")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
...
}
```

Then my Startup.cs swagger code in the ConfigureServices Method looks like this, (edited to include contribution from Iain Carlin to include controller header comments) :

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    // Set Title and version
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My Example API", Version = "v1", Description = "The API for my application" });
    // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
    var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
    // pick comments from classes, including controller summary comments
    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath, includeControllerXmlComments: true); 
    // _OR_ enable the annotations on Controller classes [SwaggerTag], if no class comments present
    c.EnableAnnotations();
});
```

Then my Controller will get decorated

[image: Result from SwaggerTag in Swashbuckle]

Comment: just notice: need to add nuget package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations` :) Thank you for help!

Comment: Make sure to add this to your .csproj file. Or you will get an .xml file does not exist error

<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>

Comment: good to see we can re-use the below comment tag for swagger documentation
<summary>
<param>
<return>
<response>, may read this https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/enhance-swagger-documentation-with-annotations-in-asp-net-core-d2981803e299 for Illustrated step by step guide

Answer (score 16):

I was looking for a similar answer and hoping to be able to use the summary XML comments on the controller class to provide the controller description. Turns out you can do this by adding includeControllerXmlComments: true in the Swagger configuration in startup:

```html
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath, includeControllerXmlComments: true);
    });
```

So then:

```html
    /// <summary>
    /// My controller description
    /// </summary>
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
```

displays as:

[image]

Comment: good!, but this adds comments to all controllers, if i i need to annotate only some (say "in progress"), then use `SwaggerTag`

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [SwaggerOperationAttribute](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/1b8e109cdb2e21b57584ef4596a0d1a13af8b7eb/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen/Annotations/SwaggerOperationAttribute.cs) for that:

```
public class MyController 
{
    [SwaggerOperation(Tags = new[] { "XYZ - A collection of XYZ APIs" })]
    public IActionResult MyAction() 
    {
    }
}
```

In Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version 1.0.0-rc3 the [ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ApiExplorerSettingsAttribute.cs) is used to include an action in a specific Swagger document.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but just in case someone else lands here - looking for an answer for the core version - and for the sake of completeness, I'll leave another easy option. From the [docs](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#customize-operation-tags-eg-for-ui-grouping):

### Customize Operation Tags (e.g. for UI Grouping)

The Swagger spec allows one or more "tags" to be assigned to an operation. The Swagger generator will assign the controller name as the default tag. This is particularly interesting if you're using the SwaggerUI middleware as it uses this value to group operations.

You can override the default tag by providing a function that applies tags by convention. For example, the following configuration will tag, and therefore group operations in the UI, by HTTP method:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    ...
    c.TagActionsBy(api => api.HttpMethod);
};
```

Using this way you could tag your endpoints using the logic that best fits your needs. You pass the lambda to the `TagActionsBy` method and return the tag you want.

For the sample you provided we could do:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    ...
    c.TagActionsBy(api => "XYZ - A collection of XYZ APIs");
};
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a new attribute, replacing the old [SwaggerTag(...)] in NSwag.Annotations:

```
[OpenApiTag("This is name", Description = "This is description")]
```

Which results to:

[image]

Note, the first attribute *name* has to be specified, you can either keep the name the same or rename the controller.

Unfortunately, it seems that there is no easy solution for the ///summary comments to be added to the docs. This approach worked without any extra configuration.

Comment: I have added NSwag.Annotations from nuget and added OpenApiTag on the Controllers but it is not showing in swagger. is there any other configuration that we need to mention?

Comment: @GobindGupta, sorry, I don't recall setting anything else, however it might be that the project was already set up before.

Answer (score 0):

Neat and easy method using NSwag for .NET Core 3.1. Just add the code below and you get a nice description for controllers and the APIs. Plus some description at the top of the swagger page.

**Startup.cs - method: public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)**

```
        services.AddSwaggerDocument(config =>
        {
            config.OperationProcessors.Add(
                    new AspNetCoreOperationSecurityScopeProcessor("JWT"));
            // Add summary to the controller
            config.UseControllerSummaryAsTagDescription = true;
            // Add JWT authorization option at the top
            config.AddSecurity("JWT", Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Type = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                Name = "Authorization",
                In = OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
                Description = "Type into the textbox: Bearer {your JWT Token}"
            });
            config.PostProcess = document =>
            {
                document.Info.Version = "1";
                document.Info.Title = "title";
                document.Info.Description = "description";
            };
        });
```

Method: public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
Add this:

```
        //CONFIG: Configure NSwag
        app.UseOpenApi();
        app.UseSwaggerUi3();
```

Then, at the top of the controller class and methods, just add a summary, for example:

```
/// <summary>
/// your description
/// </summary>
[ApiController]
[Route(your route)]
public class NameController : ControllerBase
```

It will give a nice and clean as the live demo here: https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/