# How to define controller descriptions in ASP.NET Core Swagger (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am trying Swagger in ASP.NET Core WebApi project and everything works fine - except controller descriptions.

For instance, I have UredskoPoslovanjeController and description in Swagger UI is UredskoPoslovanje and I can not find a way to change it.

Only solution I found is listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369914/does-swagger-asp-net-core-have-a-controller-description)
However, I think this is in conflict with API versions since versioning uses exact same attribute `[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName="v2")]`

Here is swagger.json for this part:
[UredskoPoslovanje part in swagger.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIpT1.png)

And my controlle is defined like this:

```
   /// <summary>
    /// Uredsko poslovanje API
    /// </summary>
    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UredskoPoslovanjeController : Controller
    {
        private LinkDbContext ctx;

        public UredskoPoslovanjeController(LinkDbContext ctx)
        {
            this.ctx = ctx;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Vraća broj pismena za zadani OIB
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="OIB">OIB korisnika za koji se traži broj pismena</param>
        /// <returns>Vraća broj pronađenih pismena</returns>
        /// <response code="200">Vraća broj pismena za traženi OIB</response>
        /// <response code="400">OIB ne postoji</response>        
        /// <response code="401">Nemate pristup metodi (neispravna autorizacija)</response>        
        [HttpGet("BrojPismena/{oib}")]
        public ActionResult<BrojPismenaModel> DajBrojPismena(string OIB)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(OIB)) return BadRequest("OIB ne smije biti prazan");
            else
            {
                var osoba = ctx.Osoba.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Oib == OIB);
                if (osoba == null) return BadRequest($"Osoba s OIB-om '{OIB}' ne postoji!");
                else
                {
                    return Ok(new BrojPismenaModel() { OIB = OIB, BrojPismena = ctx.UpPismeno.Count() });
                }
            }            
        }
    }
```

I would expect "Uredsko poslovanje API" as controller description, but that does not happen - [swagger ui screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xO0g.png)

Any idea how to properly set controller description?

Thanks, 
Mario

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default the comments for the controller are not included.  The IncludeXmlComments method has a version that takes a boolean to indicate whether the controller XML comments should be used. The code below is from my Startup : ConfigureServices method.

Original:

```
var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
```

New:

```
var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath, true);  // <== Added the true here, to show the controller description
```

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate via SwaggerTag attribute

```js
[ApiController]
[SwaggerTag("This is an example SwaggerTag")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase
```

as seen in Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations version 6.x

Make sure you have performed all what Brad Bruce has asked you to do.

Comment: this not work out of the box as you mentioned, pls provide more information

Answer (score -1):

Per the documentation, you can annotate controller actions and models with XML comments. Not the controller itself.

https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#include-descriptions-from-xml-comments

Comment: So, there is no way to do this?
I have seen examples in other languages where this can be done with @Api notation, so I was hoping there is a way to do it in ASP.NET Core as well.

Comment: Swashbuckle is open source and you might be able to modify it to do what you want. Depends on how badly you want this functionality, I guess.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the linked page where it states that controllers could not have a comment on them.  Please see my answer.  It's not on by default, but it is available.