# Swagger (Swashbuckle) - How to add text under an endpoint

Tags: c#, api, swagger, swashbuckle

The following screen shot shows where I would like the text to be.  I am using Swashbuckle-swagger in .net and can't find a settings to put in description text for a controller.

[image: Screen shot of a swagger page showing new text under endpoint name saying "how do I add text here"]

Comment: there is a lot of samples here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369914/does-swagger-asp-net-core-have-a-controller-description

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Swagger (Asp.Net Core) have a controller description?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369914/does-swagger-asp-net-core-have-a-controller-description)

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping the put a large paragraph under the header area.  The description beside the text area will already have a short summary.

Comment: I updated the image in the example to help