# How can I document REST resources with Swashbuckle?

Tags: c#, rest, swagger

When I prototyped my API with Swagger-editor, I included some descriptive text at the resource level:

[image: Resource descriptions for customers and devices]

In the YAML, this looks like:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: ...
  description: ...
  ...
- name: Customers
  description: Access to customer information
- name: Devices
  description: Access to device information
```

But when I implement this API with a controller written in C# I don't see where I can put this information so Swashbuckle will put it in the Swagger output.

I thought maybe if I put a `<summary>` above the `class` line for the controller it would show up where I expect but that text doesn't seem to show up in my Swagger output.  I think I'm missing something.  I've googled a bit without finding any relevant answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369914/does-swagger-asp-net-core-have-a-controller-description is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) has the definition under: [Include Descriptions from XML comments](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#include-descriptions-from-xml-comments). Basically what you will have to do is to Add:

```
<GenerateDocumentationFile>True</GenerateDocumentationFile>
```

in your .csproj's PropertyGroup and after that navigate to Program.cs file where you configure your swagger and  similar option configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    // Other configuration

    options.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml"));
});
```

after that you can use XML comments to describe your resources. here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r62U.png) of this example.

Comment: Thank you but no, that's not what I mean.  I don't seem to be able to format this comment but if you think of the Swagger doc as an HTML outline, the API name is an `<H1>`, each resource has an `<H2>` and each endpoint is an `<H3>`.  What I want is to add a `<p>` under the `<H2>`, a general description of the resource, not tied to any specific endpoint.

Comment: I edited the question to show what I mean from my prototype.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40369914/does-swagger-asp-net-core-have-a-controller-description may be what I was looking for.